# Hibernate performs several queries instead of one

Tags: hibernate, hql

I've been trying to optimize the way hibernate achieve some information, but I can't understand next issue.

I've one entity like this

```
public class AnoEmp{
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Empleado
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_EMPLEADO", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Empleado empleado;
}
...
```

And another one like this

```
public class Empleado{
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to AnoEmp
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="empleado", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<AnoEmp> anosEmp;
...
```

Althoug it's eager (and it has to be like that) It performs N + 1 queries one for the list of AnoEmp and one per Empleado. But it could be done with just one query (as I expected becouse of @eager)

I found this [Why hibernate perform two queries for eager load a @OneToOne bidirectional association?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381521/why-hibernate-perform-two-queries-for-eager-load-a-onetoone-bidirectional-assoc) but can't get mine running properly. Any suggestion? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I have been found always working is the use of `join` in the JPQL e.g.

```
   "from Empleado emp join emp.anosEmp"
```

Comment: I tried, new select make explicitly the join, but still get N + 1 queries... Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for keeping `@OneToMany(mappedBy="empleado", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` as `Lazy`?

Comment: Yes, I dont need anoEmp everytime i need empleado. In the other way is different. The query anyway gets AnoEmp, so I suppose empleado should be loaded eagerly and with one query.